# Newbie question: Will "Pending" change to "Current" when Status Override reaches the selected date?

Tags: civimember, status, pending

I have a member who has paid for a new membership and asked it to start when his current membership expires. At the moment, both read as "Current." If I use "Status Override" until a select date and change his status to pending, will that "pending" automatically change to "current" on that selected date?

Tony

Comment: can you clarify why his 'new membership' is not just being treated as a renewal? is he changing Memb Types?

Comment: Yes, he is changing membership types.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you should set up your membership status rules and live by them, and not use "status override" :-) Documentation on the membership status rules can be found here: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/membership/defining-memberships/#membership-status-rules

Comment: Ideally, my predecessor would have done that. But he clearly wasn't knowledgeable about CiviCRM's status rules. So I'm stuck with this question about how to provide a member with a future membership with a different membership type.

Answer (score 1):

This is very likely to happen, but it depends on your membership status rules, as Erik notes.  It sounds like you'd like to change the start date, not the status.

Remember that membership status works by finding the first status (reading from top to bottom) where the current date is between the two dates defined as the Start and End Events.  You can find the rules at **Administer menu » CiviMember » Membership Status Rules**.

Comment: and do not forget to check if the scheduled job that updates membership status runs! (Administer>System Settings>Scheduled jobs and you are checking the one called Update Membership Statuses (Daily)

Comment: This particular contact has been a long standing member. He is changing his membership type from a basic member to a regular member (an upgrade in our membership tiers). He doesn't want the regular membership to kick in until June however. So his "start date" (as I understand it) would remain the same from when he first became a basic member and his "end date" would run through when his regular membership expires. Or does one have different start and end dates for different membership types/tiers?